# Change text color everywhere math mode is used

Tags: latex

By default math mode has the same color as the rest of the document text. I want it in such a way that the document text remains unaffected but anywhere math mode is used the color of the text within the math mode is whichever other preferred color.

Answer (score 0):

All math environments? Add `\AtBeginEnvironment{<environment name>}` (defined in [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) in your preamble. Example below demonstrates this with `equation` but you would need to add any other environment you use, as well

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{red}}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  x = y
\end{equation}

\lipsum[3][1]

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:2}
  z = a + b
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```